# error creation of mysql database (docker image)

Tags: mysql, docker, jelastic

During MuraCMS setup the following error occurs. Please suggest.

```
Error:
Error during database creation (1):
Error during creation of MySQL datbase: 
can't access password protected information from the configuration, 
no password is defined for this web context -
```

Comment: Have you set the password in the web admin panel?  https://dev.lucee.org/t/cant-access-password-protected-information-from-the-configuration-no-password-is-defined-for-this/516

Comment: Why do you think is a docker problem? Does it works in host?